# Ruby's *args causing seg fault when no args supplied

Tags: ruby, rspec, args

I'm trying to do some scripted GUI testing in Windows using Ruby.  I'm leveraging the guidance of a [pragprog book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/idgtr/scripted-gui-testing-with-ruby) and I'm hitting a bit of a snag.  I've factored out some code to help with the repeatitive mapping of win32api functions.  The code is as follows:

```
module WindowsGui

  def self.def_api(function, parameters, return_value)              
    api = Win32API.new 'user32', function, parameters, return_value

    define_method(function.snake_case) do |*args|                  
      api.call *args                                                
    end

  end
end
```

...So I can use that block to define several win32APIs in the module in the following fashion:

```
def_api 'FindWindow', ['P', 'P'], 'L'
```

I've got some RSpec tests to ensure this behaves as it should.

```
  it 'wraps a Windows call with a method' do
    find_window(nil, nil).should_not == 0
  end
  
  it 'enforces the argument count' do
    lambda {find_window}.should raise_error
  end
```

Everything works fine as for the first test, the second results in a seg fault.  Seems that if I call this with no args, I can't touch *args - but I can do a args.length to see that it's empty.

Why would this result in a seg fault and not an exception?  Would it be acceptable to resolve this through something like..

```
  raise BadArgs if args.length == 0
```

Yet another question that is way too long - sorry for that.

TIA!
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason it's seg faulting is because somewhere underneath `Win32API` the lack of arguments is translating into one or more NULL pointer dereferences.

If you are going to create functions like this then you should consider adding a per-api-call, boolean-returning argument validation block (or lambda) as an argument to `def_api` which you would then invoke as the first part of your derived function. Something like this:

```
def self.def_api(function, parameters, return_value, &valid_args?)              
  api = Win32API.new 'user32', function, parameters, return_value

  define_method(function.snake_case) do |*args|
    if valid_args? and valid_args?.call(*args)               
      api.call *args
    else
      // raise argument error, etc
    end                                         
  end

end
```

Then

```
def_api 'FindWindow', ['P', 'P'], 'L', { |args| return true if // API specific checks succeed }
```

UPDATE: Adding more color at questioner's request

The `&valid_args?` is the name of a block parameter. The ampersand prefix (&) is how you tell ruby that you passing a block. You can only pass one block to a methodand it must be the last parameter in the argument list. The question mark suffix (?) is just a convention in Ruby programming for naming functions which return boolean values.

If a block is passed you invoke it with `&block.call(args)`

To call a method with a block argument you do something like this:

```
method { |args| // block implementation }
```

or

```
method do |args|
  // block implementation
end
```

The `args` are passed to the block through the `call method`. Hope this helps.

Comment: So the { |args| ... } block in the def_api call would act as an args validator (i.e. called by valid_args)?  Sorry, my knowledge of ruby isn't so deep sometimes.  Also, I'm a little confused by the valid_args?.call(*args)  Could you provide a little more insight as to what's going on there?

Thanks a ton for the quick answer, much appreciated...

Comment: Rad - helps a ton.  Thanks again for taking the time to explain, much appreciated.